# KML polygon coordinates sorting (clockwise, counterwise)

Tags: coordinates, kml, polygon

I have a problem with visualising polygon on google earth. I'm reading .xlsx file from the top to the bottom (in java) and I have a set of coordinates (x,y). My app is producing .kml file using JAK lib. After that when I import this .kml file into google earth I have wrong polygon shapes. Here is the example:

[image: wrong polygon shape]

The thing is that in kml file coordinates are in the sequence as they appear on the image. Last coordinate is by default connected to the first one and this is the problem. 
How can I sort the coordinates that this shape will be a rectagle? Of course this is the simplest example. I have much more complicated polygons (in the file) than the rectangle one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your polygons are convex you can implement any [convex-hull algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms). This will work for your example but not with more complex polygons.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. I did this. I even found very nice convex hull algorithm written in Java. Unfortunately it occured that some of the polygons are not convex.

Answer (score 1):

KML's [LinearRing](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linearring) structure that you'd use in the Polygon is a ring, so the polygon is drawn linearly in the order that you specify in the ring. So if you want to draw a rectangle, they'd need to be ordered 1, 2, 4 3.

There's nothing within KML to tell it to interpret the ring differently. You'll need to either sort them in your java application when you're reading the XSLX, or have whoever is providing you the data send you the list of points in the correct order. I'm not sure what the domain is of what you're doing, but it doesn't make sense to me to send them in any way to you other than as a linear ring of points int he order you'd draw the lines.

Comment: Of course you're right. I know that the order is wrong and I also know that this is not a KML thing to deal with the coordinates sorting. My question is how to sort (in java) coordinates so that I will get a rectangle polygon than then one I attached on the picture.